# Number of participants in Room (firebase chat)

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How many participants can be add in one single **room** in firebase chat?

I have search lot but not get any answer. At firebase site:-https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ .

> "There is a limit of 100,000 simultaneous connections per database"

is mention, but that's 10k users online simultaneously.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit Firebase imposes is per database. To know the limit per room, you will need to determine how you model your chat rooms into the database(s).

If you model a single room as a single database, that will lead to a maximum number of 100.000 simultaneous users in that chat room: so 100.000 users chatting at the same time. To give you some idea: most chat rooms become unusable (due to the amount of messages) by the time you have more than a couple of hundred simultaneous users.

Also note this in the pricing FAQ:

> The Spark plan limit is 100 and cannot be raised. The Flame and Blaze plans have a limit of 100,000 simultaneous connections per database. **If you need more than 100,000 simultaneous connections, contact Firebase support.**